# Trim output of running program

Tags: bash, sed, trim

I have a program that when it runs, outputs hundreds of lines starting with "Info:" and a few lines that have useful output. To make things easier, I have created a simple python and bash combination script to emulate the issue I'm having:

wait_2sec.py:

```
import time

print("Hello!")
time.sleep(2)
print("Goodbye!")
```

I am attempting to trim my output by running:

```
 python wait_2sec.py | sed '/Goodbye/d'
```

However, sed does not output Hello! until after the python script has finished. I don't know whether the pipe waits until after the program is finished to begin running the sed command, or if the sed command is the hangup.
I am open to using another command to trim output if sed does not work for this use-case.

Comment: Why not simply use bash? `(echo "Hello!"; sleep 2; echo "Goodbye!") | sed '/Goodbye/d'`? or you can use a brace-enclosed list instead of a subshell for `echo` and `sleep`, but you will need to separate with spaces and end with `';'`,  e.g. `{ echo "Hello!"; sleep 2; echo "Goodbye!"; } | sed '/Goodbye/d'`

Comment: Tangentially, sounds like a design flaw in your Python program. With `logging` you can easily turn off all `INFO:` output by setting a logging level. These messages should be printed on standard error, not standard output; `logging` does that correctly out of the box, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your script using the following command:

```
unbuffer python wait_2sec.py | sed '/Goodbye/d'
```

Refrence: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200413

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know whether the pipe waits until after the program is finished to begin running the sed command, or if the sed command is the hangup.

It's actually neither of both, it's that `python` normally buffers its output (if not to a terminal) until the buffer is full, hence Moustapha's suggestion may work provided that `unbuffer` is installed. But you can simply use `python`'s built-in option `-u` (*Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered.*) instead:

```
python -u wait_2sec.py | sed '/Goodbye/d'
```